# Java Date representation difference

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, android-date

Is the formatter representation `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"` is correct way to format the date.

Note that here I've used small 's'(instead of capital 'S') to indicate milliseconds which results wrong time.

If yes what is the difference between `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS.`

Why some are in small letters and some are in capital letters to indicate the date format.

Here is the sample code which shows the difference

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss");

    try {
        Date d = dateFormatLocal.parse("2015-07-21 11:01:27.063");
        Date d1 = dateFormatLocal1.parse("2015-07-21 11:01:27.063");
        System.out
                .println("------------- Sync Completed in Date -------------"
                        + d.getTime());
        System.out
                .println("------------- Sync Completed in Date -------------"
                        + d1.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//OutPut is 
//------------- Date in SSS -------------1437456687063
//------------- Date in sss -------------1437456723000
```

Comment: You are stumble with multiple questions. What is your exact question ? Quite unclear for me, what exactly you are trying to achieve. Voting to close.

Comment: Y U NOT READ [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered,  the correct pattern for milliseconds is SSS, while sss represents seconds.

They are different capitalization because they represent different parts of the date/time.

In the same way that it would be incorrect to use "yy" four hours,  it is incorrect to use "sss" for milliseconds.